# Setting the default submit value for a jquery ui slider Rails 4

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby-on-rails, jquery-ui, uislider

Currently I am struggling to get it so that when I submit a jquery range slider without having moved the default values to include anything in the params hash. If I move either of the sliders at all I get both values in slider to show up however if I don't touch them (i.e the defaults suit me) nothing appears. The code is the following: (where f. is a form_for a user)

```
  <label class="label">Regular slider (<span id="slider-value">0</span>)</label>
          <div id="slider"></div>
          <%= f.hidden_field :min_v%>
          <%= f.hidden_field :max_v%>


<script>
    $('#slider1').slider({
        min: 1,
        max: 12,
        range: true,
        values: [3,9],
        slide: function(event, ui)
        {
            $('#slider1-value1').text(ui.values[0]);
            $('#slider1-value2').text(ui.values[1]);
        },
        change: function(event, ui) {
            $('input#project_min_v').val(ui.values[0]);
            $('input#project_max_v').val(ui.value[1]);
        }

    });
</script>
```